# Updating Table Expiration via API

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to update the retention time of an existing table through the API? I would prefer not recreating the table if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use [Tables: patch](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/patch) to set/update [expirationTime](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#expirationTime) table property